# Issue with compilation in Android project: 'Could not create task' error - React Native DeepAR

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native, deepar

I am currently working on an Android project using DeepAR and React Native. I'm encountering an error while trying to compile my project. The error message I'm getting is:

```
DeepAR: Execution failed for task ':tasks'. > Could not create task ':react-native-deepar:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. > In order to compile Java 9+ source, please set compileSdkVersion to 30 or above.
```

I have already set **compileSdkVersion** to 33 in my project, and I couldn't find any issues related to this specific problem. Here are the relevant parts of my build configuration:

```
buildscript {
ext {
    buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileSdkVersion = 33
    targetSdkVersion = 33

    ndkVersion = "26.1.10909125"
}}
```

I've checked the documentation and forums but haven't been able to resolve this. Can anyone point me in the right direction or provide insights on what might be causing this error? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!